# Check that Office 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies is installed via registry

Tags: registry, office-interop

How do I check if Microsoft 2007 Primary Interop Assemblies is installed only by querying into the registry ?

Comment: Where do the registry entries have to be? [This is for the 2010 version check](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a48dd1f3-c6c3-4925-8c8c-da177173f12a/how-can-i-detect-if-office-2010-primary-interop-has-been-installed-using-the-registry-keys?forum=vsto)

Comment: I don't know, this is part of my question.

Comment: Did you take a look at the attached link? Does it gibe you some hints?